# Why is the conductance of a metal-insulator-metal tunnel junction parabolic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling, semiclassical, density-of-states

For bias voltages below the tunnel junction barrier heights (and below the Fowler-Nordheim limit), tunnel junctions have a parabolic conductance as a function of bias. Is this due to the metallic density of states as a function of energy, the shape of the tunnel barrier, etc.?